# React Native sharing image to Instagram from DocumentDirectoryPath

Tags: android, react-native, instagram

I have made custom native module for React Native that's need to share images from path `/data/user/0/com.instagramscheduler/files/downloaded.jpg` (that is my application) and to be clear **file exists in that folder**.

But the problem is that it is not sharing, when I share to Instagram it says that it is **unable to load file**. I have checked and `uri.toString() == "file:///data/user/0/com.instagramscheduler/files/downloaded.jpg"`

My React Native custom share method:

```
public void share() {
    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File("/data/user/0/com.instagramscheduler/files/downloaded.jpg");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share To"));
}
```

Here is my **manifest** if it helps:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.instagramscheduler">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Here is **logcat** if needed (starting from when share dialog open till it fails to share on Instagram): https://gist.github.com/Azael05x/f706925668ce9b8dd9970a81ed23e979

Answer (score 1):

1. As I was downloading and saving images instead of saving image to your application folder, save it to [public folder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)). And it worked, because Instagram did not have access to my apps private folders.
2. Then I checked on other phone and it did not work there. Reason was that Instagram was with disabled storage permission.